# How do I search an array using a partial string, and return the index?

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, indexing

I want to search through an array using a partial string, and then get the index where that string is found. For example:

```
a = ["This is line 1", "We have line 2 here", "and finally line 3", "potato"]
a.index("potato") # this returns 3
a.index("We have") # this returns nil
```

Using `a.grep` will return the full string, and using `a.any?` will return a correct true/false statement, but neither returns the index where the match was found, or at least I can't figure out how to do it.

I'm working on a piece of code that reads a file, looks for a specific header, and then returns the index of that header so it can use it as an offset for future searches. Without starting my search from a specific index, my other searches will get false positives.

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-3D-7E

Comment: Do you want only the array index where the string was found, or the array index, plus the offset into the string in that array element?

Comment: Just the first one, but I would be interested in the second one just for future use, because that sounds like it would be very useful to know!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use a block.

```
a.index{|s| s.include?("We have")}
```

or

```
a.index{|s| s =~ /We have/}
```

Comment: Amazing! I thought include would only work with true/false, but I was wrong! This works perfectly, thank you!